# Trouble implementing the Ionic Select Searchable Component

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am currently learning Ionic framework, and I recently tried the select searchable component to select a single item and another one for selecting multiple items.

But when I compiled the project, I got the following error:

```
Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'canReset' since it isn't a known property of 'select-searchable'.
1. If 'select-searchable' is an Angular component and it has 'canReset' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'select-searchable' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
[canSearch] = "true"
(onChange) = "userChanged($event)"
[ERROR ->][canReset]= "true"
okButtonText = "Proceed with users"
resetButtonText = "Clear selected"
"): ng:///AppModule/HomePage.html@33:4
Can't bind to 'noItemsFoundText' since it isn't a known property of 'select-searchable'.
1. If 'select-searchable' is an Angular component and it has 'noItemsFoundText' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'select-searchable' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
resetButtonText = "Clear selected"
(onClose) = "onClose($event)"
[ERROR ->][noItemsFoundText] = "'No users found.'"
[shouldStoreItemValue] = "false">
</select-searchable>"): ng:///AppModule/HomePage.html@37:4
at syntaxError (compiler.js:486)
at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:24674)
at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:34629)
at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:34604)
at compiler.js:34505
at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:34505)
at compiler.js:34375
at Object.then (compiler.js:475)
at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34374)
```

I've tried without the multiple select searchable component and it worked fine. But I want to test the multiple select component also.

Here is the code from the project:

Home.ts:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SelectSearchableComponent } from 'ionic-select-searchable';

@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
@ViewChild('myselect') selectComponent: SelectSearchableComponent;

user = null;
userIds = [];

users = [
{
    id: 0,
    name: 'Simon Grimm',
    country: 'Germany'
},
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Max Lynch',
    country: 'Wisconsin'
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Nic Raboy',
    country: 'California'
}
];


constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private toastCtrl: ToastController) {

}

userChanged(event:{component: SelectSearchableComponent, value:any}){
    //user selected
    console.log('event: ', event);
}

onClose()
{
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: 'Thanks for your selection',
    duration: 2000
    });
    toast.present();
    console.log('users: ', this.userIds);
}

openFromCode()
{
    this.selectComponent.open();
}

}
```

Home.html:

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>
    Ionic Searchable Select
    </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Select user</ion-label>
    <select-searchable
    item-content
    [(ngModel)] = "user"
    [items] = "users"
    itemValueField = "id"
    itemTextField = "name"
    [canSearch] = "true"
    (onChange) = "userChanged($event)">
</select-searchable>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Select multiple users</ion-label>
    <select-searchable #myselect
    item-content
    [isMultiple] = "true"
    [(ngModel)] = "userIds"
    [items] = "users"
    itemValueField = "id"
    itemTextField = "name"
    [canSearch] = "true"
    (onChange) = "userChanged($event)"
    [canReset]= "true"
    okButtonText = "Proceed with users"
    resetButtonText = "Clear selected"
    (onClose) = "onClose($event)"
    [noItemsFoundText] = "'No users found.'"
    [shouldStoreItemValue] = "false">
</select-searchable>
</ion-item>

<button ion-button full color="primary" (click) = "openFromCode()">Open select</button>
</ion-content>
```

And also when I click on the "Open select" button, it returns the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
at HomePage.webpackJsonp.194.HomePage.openFromCode (VM1614 main.js:95)
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (HomePage.html:43)
at handleEvent (VM1613 vendor.js:13915)
at callWithDebugContext (VM1613 vendor.js:15424)
at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (VM1613 vendor.js:15011)
at dispatchEvent (VM1613 vendor.js:10330)
at VM1613 vendor.js:10955
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (VM1613 vendor.js:39452)
at t.invokeTask (VM1607 polyfills.js:3)
at Object.onInvokeTask (VM1613 vendor.js:5077)
```

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: I found solutions from this article https://ionicacademy.com/ionic-searchable-select-custom/#comment-4524230649

Answer (score 0):

For the compilation error you should import this component's module in your AppModule

In app.module.ts make sure you have these lines:

```
import { SelectSearchableModule } from 'ionic-select-searchable';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        SelectSearchableModule
    ]
})
```

For the second error, you have to identify this component in the html with the # character, in your case the @ViewChild, defines it as myselect:

```
<select-searchable
    #myselect 
    item-content
    [(ngModel)] = "user"
    [items] = "users"
    itemValueField = "id"
    itemTextField = "name"
    [canSearch] = "true"
    (onChange) = "userChanged($event)">
</select-searchable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you have installed and added them in the following places
1

1. app.module.ts
2. home.module.ts
3. home.page.ts

And by "add" I mean to do the following

import like

```
import { SelectSearchableModule } from 'ionic-select-searchable';
```

and add them to the @NgModule imports like

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        SelectSearchableModule
    ]
})
```